# fill away with user input javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to fill an array inside object with user input 
my object is

```
var person = [];
var SalesPerson = {
    name: "", 
    id: 0, 
    amount: [],
    total: 0      
};
```

and i want to fill the amount array with float input received from the user.
i tried

```
sales.amount.push(parseFloat(prompt("Please enter sales amount:")));
```

put i didn't not do the job i want

my loop to get the user input is

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  var sales = Object.create(SalesPerson);
  sales.name = prompt("Enter person Name :");
    while (nameRegExp.test(sales.name) == false) {
     alert("INPUT ERROR! Name must include at least one letter");
     sales.name = prompt("Please enter sales person name :");
     }

  sales.id = prompt("Enter person ID :");
    while (idRegExp.test(sales.id) == false) {
    alert("INPUT ERROR! Sales person ID only accapt numbers");
    sales.id = prompt("Please enter sales person ID :");
     }


  sales.amount.push(parseFloat(prompt("Please enter sales amount:")));
  person.push(sales);
```

}

the user input gonna have 4 values to be stored on the amount array 
E.g., [1000000.39,   890000.23,  760000.34,   540000.98]

the question is :

•   salesName: must include at least one alphabet letter, no requirements for other characters
•   salesID: only digits are allowed
•   salesAmount: a list of 4 non-negative decimal numbers for the four (4) types of cars in the above order. E.g., [1000000.39,   890000.23,  760000.34,   540000.98] means this salesperson sales amount for "Mercedes Benz" is $1000000.39, 
                                     sales amount for "Audi" is $890000.23,
                                  …

Comment: You declared your variable with the name "SalesPerson" but your `.push()` call just says "sales". Which is it?

Comment: sales is new object from my blueprint object SalesPerson and I saved the whole object in an array called person

Comment: blex, sales is defined in my loop. I'll edit my post to write the whole code

Comment: Sorry your question has just got more an more confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally understand you problem!

You need to create a new array when you create your new `SalesPerson`, as creating a new object doesn't create a new array object. It still references the first array.

After `var sales = Object.create(SalesPerson);` add this line `sales.amount = [];`

So the code looks like this:

```
var sales = Object.create(SalesPerson);
sales.amount = [];
```

See this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8tm3jzg/4/).

Comment: still it just stored the first value of the array amount, the rest is undefined

Comment: alert(person[0].amount[0] + "--" +person[0].amount[1] + "--" +person[0].amount[2] + "--" +person[0].amount[3]);

Comment: the first value return the rest are undefined

Comment: @RayMalk That's because you only run the sales.amount.push line once per SalesPerson.

Comment: @AshleyMedway That's a good point, but I don't think it's what OP was asking.

Comment: @DavidKnipe are you suggesting that i put sales.amount.push in a loop

Comment: If you want it to run more than once then, yes, it should be in a loop.